# How to fix build failure : Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.1:run (default-cli) on project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am facing an error when I build a spring project
[prompt error in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvSTL.png)
Below is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.formationspring</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>  
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>  
                <version>2.22.2</version>  
                <configuration>  
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>  
                </configuration>  
            </plugin>  
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

How can I fix this error ?

I try to fix a spring build error

Comment: Add the complete error message as text to your question

Comment: Looks like your application doesn't start. You should see stacktraces in the mvn output

Comment: Remove `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` and remove the `maven-surefire-plugin` it download an incompatible one. If you want to skip tests add `-DskipTests=true` to your maven execution. Remoing the `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` will probably lead to compilation errors because you should be using `jakarta.persistence` instead of `javax.persistence`.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating new workspace for your project.

Run `mvn clean install` if project fails again then run the same command with `-X` i.e. `mvn clean install -X` to get the full stack trace log (paste it here)

Comment: This what i did before and it doesn't fix my error